# Unity raycast not detecting an object which has already been detected by it before

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Shoot: MonoBehaviour

{

public Camera cam;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        shooot();
    }
}

void shooot()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hit))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
    }
}
```

The other objects have a box collider and Rigid body. The Raycast detects "Cube1" and after I shoot a raycast at something else and then again shoot a raycast at "Cube1" this code does not detect it. Why?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Comment: did you try [debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) and see if the method is even executed? If you say it does not detect it ... does it detect something else instead or nothing at all?

Comment: I am using Probuilder to build my environment. I think that's the problem. I did try debugging my code. It won't print anything if I shoot a raycast at something which has already been detected. Thanks!

Comment: No, it is not caused due to probuilder. I checked it!

Comment: If the debug shows that nothing is printing, next debug is to add the line  debug.log("shooot was called");      just before the function-call for shoot(); as it's possible there's a problem with the inputs?

Comment: Could you show the full console output at the end of this test?

Comment: Also show you're scene view. I think it might have to do with the fact that your are specifying the direction of the ray.

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR HELP! It turns out that the console won't log the same name twice(idk why), hence my raycast is working fine, it is detecting an object which has already been detected by it previously, but it is just not logging it!!

Comment: I had to run a series of test to figure this out. THANKYOU ALL!!

Comment: Does anybody know why the console won't print the same name twice??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity does log everything. It's just that if you log the same output multiple times Unity collapses into one single line. You can see this by the number indicated on the right side of the output.

*(Image taken from https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-the-console-window#5f68b4eeedbc2a002022b83d)*
[image]

If you toggle the marked "Collapse" button, it will show every single output.

Answer (score 1):

Press Collapse in the Console of the Unity Editor to toggle wherever prints and logs should be stacked (collapsed) or not, it should still log twice, but instead of appearing as two separate logs the counter on the right increases showing how many times the same equal line have been logged.